# Компьютер не видит второй монитор

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, monitor

Переустановил `Windows 10`, и при настройке компьютер отказывается нормально видеть второй монитор.
Один монитор подключен при помощи `HDMI`, второй при помощи `Display Port`. Оба кабеля рабочие, оба подключены правильно. Установлен подходящий драйвер.
Пробовал следовать инструкциям из интернета, ничего не помогает.

Также пишет `"display 2 isn't active"`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На панели Nvidia же в списке показываются два монитора. ¿У второго не ставится галочка что ли?

Comment: @user7860670 нет, не ставится

Answer (score 1):

В настройках выбрал "расширить монитор" Довольно глупо было до этого не догадаться сразу..

Comment: Если бы это был лаптоп, то еще надо было бы зайти в "темах" (!!! (совсем другое окно настройки !!!)) в "дополнительные параметры" и установить, что при закрытии крышки ничего не надо делать (иначе при ее закрытии переключение на внешний монитор идет очень долго (сам он на время отключается)). Настраивал это, не далее, как вчера.